# Difference between 'this' and 'var' when declaring variable, nodeJS

Tags: node.js, function, var

I have the next piece of code:

```
function Server() {
    this.isStarted = false;
//  var isStarted = false;

    function status() {
        return isStarted;
    }

    console.log(status());
}

var a = new Server()
```

When I run it I get

```
ReferenceError: isStarted is not defined
    at status (/a/fr-05/vol/home/stud/yotamoo/workspace/ex4/text.js:7:10)
    at new Server (/a/fr-05/vol/home/stud/yotamoo/workspace/ex4/text.js:10:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/a/fr-05/vol/home/stud/yotamoo/workspace/ex4/text.js:
```

However if I change `this.isStarted = false;` to `var isStarted = false;` everything works fine.

Does anyone care to explain why?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This referes to the owner of something. See this [article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) about this. Where as var declares a local variable.

In your case, you want to refer to know if a server is started, so you need to add 'this' to your status function.

```
function status() {
    return this.isStarted;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Long story short. Since `isStarted`, when defined as `this.isStarted = true`, is a property of the current object (JavaScript `this` keyword refers to an object where the function was called), in `status` function you will have to access it as `this.isStarted`.

Declaring it as variable (`var`) is different. Technically, `isStatus` will become a property of hidden lexical scope object. You have to access it as just `isStatus` in the whole `Server` function body and and all of the child functions.